# Excel vba - printing (array)

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, printing

quick question on why the below vba for printing won't work... If I have it set up individually (Sheet1.PrintOut) it prints out fine, but if I do it as array(Sheet1, Sheet2, Sheet3).PrintOut it doesn't work. Can anyone explain why?

```
Sub printnow()

Dim Sheet1 As Worksheet
Dim Sheet2 As Worksheet
Dim Sheet3 As Worksheet

With ThisWorkbook

Set Sheet1 = .Sheets("database1")
Set Sheet2 = .Sheets("database2")
Set Sheet3 = .Sheets("database3")

'Setting up the print setup
Sheet3.PageSetup.PaperSize = xlPaperLegal

Sheet3.PageSetup.Orientation = xlPortrait

'Print

End With

Array(Sheet1,Sheet2.Sheet3).PrintOut Copies:=1

End Sub
```

Comment: You can use `ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Array("database1", "database2", "database3")).PrintOut Copies:=1` - that would be equivalent to Excel's "Print Active Sheets" option if you had selected multiple sheets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Array` function call returns a `Variant()` containing Sheet1, Sheet2, and Sheet3. A `Variant()` doesn't have a `.PrintOut` method - it isn't an object.  If you want to call `.PrintOut` on each of the objects ***in*** the array, just loop over it:

```
Dim sheet As Variant
For Each sheet In Array(Sheet1, Sheet2, Sheet3)
    sheet.PrintOut Copies:=1
Next
```

Answer (score 3):

You can pass an array of sheet names to `Sheets` and it will process them.

`Sheets(Array("database1", "database2", "database3")).Printout  Copies:=1`

You can also use the Sheet.Name:

`Sheets(Array(Sheet1.Name, Sheet2.Name, Sheet3.Name)).Printout  Copies:=1`

Or you can use the sheet's indices:

`Sheets(Array(1,2,3)).Printout  Copies:=1`

Comment: but would it keep the page orientation/cell selection specifications that I chose?

Comment: You have the same optional printout parameters.  If you don't specify any parameters than each sheet will use the settings that were used when it was last printed

Comment: lets say I renamed the above Sheet1 as Page1, Sheet2 as Page2, and Sheet3 as Page3, with all else equal. what can I do to make Sheets(Array(Page1, Page2, Page3)).Printout work? Or is a loop the only way

Comment: I updates my answer to demonstrate the other options.